# Solution of a system of second-order differential equations

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $\alpha$ be a real number and let $u,v$ be constant vectors. Find the conditions on $\alpha$, $u$ and $v$ such that $$x(t)=\cos(\alpha t)u +\sin(\alpha t)v$$ is a solution of the system $\ddot x=Ax$.

**This is my attempt**

$\ddot x= -\alpha^2\cos(\alpha t)u-\alpha^2\sin(\alpha t)v$

Now, $$\ddot x-Ax=-\alpha^2\cos(\alpha t)u-\alpha^2\sin(\alpha t)v-A\cos(\alpha t)u-A\sin(\alpha t)v=0$$

$$\implies\ -(\alpha^2I+A)\big(\cos(\alpha t)u+\sin(\alpha t)v\big)=0$$

This implies $\cos(\alpha t)u+\sin(\alpha t)v=0\implies\ \frac{-u}{v}=\tan(\alpha t)$,

which is impossible since $u$ and $v$ are constant vectors.

**OR**  $\alpha^2I+A=0 \implies \alpha^2I=-A$.

Is my proof until here correct? And how can I complete it?

Comment: You need one more step. You've proved that every vector of that form is eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $-\alpha^2$

Comment: do you mean that $u,v$ are eigenvector of $A$ !! I didn't get it . any more  explanation ?

Comment: @RafaBudría .....

Comment: Not sure, only checking the logic of the question... I think that you have to prove that if $A$ has only the eigenvalue $-\alpha^2$ (as you have proved), $A$ is proportional to the identity matrix. And it seems very easy. I'm sorry for not to be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're good up to here
$$
(\mathbf{A} + \alpha^2 \mathbf{I})[\cos(\alpha t)\mathbf{u} + \sin(\alpha t)\mathbf{v}] = 0
$$
Now, since this must be true at all times, it must in particular be true at $\alpha t = 0$ and $\alpha t = \pi/2$. This gives the following conditions
\begin{eqnarray}
(\mathbf{A} + \alpha^2 \mathbf{I})\mathbf{u} &=&0\\
(\mathbf{A} + \alpha^2 \mathbf{I})\mathbf{v} &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
From here I think you can work out how $\alpha$, $\mathbf{u}$, and $\mathbf{v}$ relate to $\mathbf{A}$.